# robot.txt запрещает просканировать изображения

Tags: robots.txt, google-search, feed

В `MerchantCenter` не могу залить фид данных. Ругается, что `robots.txt` запрещает просканировать изображения товаров.
Что нужно прописать или разрешить в `robots.txt`? `OpenCart`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*route=account/
Disallow: /*route=affiliate/
Disallow: /*route=checkout/
Disallow: /*route=product/search
Disallow: /index.php?route=product/product*&manufacturer_id=
Disallow: /admin
Disallow: /catalog
Disallow: /system
Disallow: /*?sort=
Disallow: /*&sort=
Disallow: /*?order=
Disallow: /*&order=
Disallow: /*?limit=
Disallow: /*&limit=
Disallow: /*?filter_name=
Disallow: /*&filter_name=
Disallow: /*?filter_sub_category=
Disallow: /*&filter_sub_category=
Disallow: /*?filter_description=
Disallow: /*&filter_description=
Disallow: /*?tracking=
Disallow: /*&tracking=
Disallow: /*compare-products
Disallow: /*search
Disallow: /*cart
Disallow: /*checkout
Disallow: /*login
Disallow: /*logout
Disallow: /*vouchers
Disallow: /*wishlist
Disallow: /*my-account
Disallow: /*order-history
Disallow: /*newsletter
Disallow: /*return-add
Disallow: /*forgot-password
Disallow: /*downloads
Disallow: /*returns
Disallow: /*transactions
Disallow: /*create-account
Disallow: /*recurring
Disallow: /*address-book
Disallow: /*reward-points
Disallow: /*affiliate-forgot-password
Disallow: /*create-affiliate-account
Disallow: /*affiliate-login
Disallow: /*affiliates
Disallow: /
```

Comment: Вас последняя строчка не смущает?

Comment: OpenCart или Disallow: / ?  Если вы знаете, то поделитесь знаниями. Зачем вы пишите, смущает меня что-то или не смущает?

Comment: Удалил последнюю строку "Disallow: /". Не помогло.